# Handling ActiveX radio buttons (groupname) when duplicating sheet with ActiveX radio

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I have an excel source sheet with many ActiveX radiobuttons which I'm copying using a VBA script.

For this to work I need to adapt the groupname of the radiobuttons to the name of the sheet (available as variable n )

The solution I'm going for is to add the name of the sheet to the end or start of each groupname;

```
currentradiobuttongroupname = currentradiobuttongroupname + n
```

So far I have:

```
Sub radioomzetter(ActiveSheet, n)
  Dim Ctrl As OLEObject
  For Each Ctrl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
      If TypeName(Ctrl.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
          Ctrl.Object.GroupName = Ctrl.Object.GroupName && n
      End If
  Next Ctrl
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this gives a syntax error. I'd appreciate any and all help.

Comment: ...GroupName && n doesn't look right. One & should suffice.

Comment: Thanks Variatus, this was the solution (I will proceed to bump my head against the wall for the coming minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .GroupName && n doesn't look right. One & should suffice. – Variatus

Comment: No answer needed, because the question is off-topic due to *"Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. "* Therefore it should be close voted I think.

Comment: If anyone wants to copy an excel sheet with radiobuttons with separate groups then this or similar code would be needed.

Whether or not this code is useful to others is not something I'd know